# Слетает авторизация на сайте при закрытии браузера

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Есть сайт на nuxt. Если авторизоваться на сайте с пк и закрыть браузер то все ок и авторизация сохраняется, но если со смартфона, и закрыть браузер, то авторизация слетает. Сайт просто адаптивный - логика одинаковая и для пк и для мобайл.

Comment: А где токен храниться?

Comment: В смысле где? В storage приложения.

Comment: В каком сторедж приложении? Это что такое? Если вы имеете ввиду локал сторедж, то он на каждом браузере и устройстве свой

Comment: Ну, я про это и говорю. Почему он должен отличаться на мобильных устройствах?

Comment: Во первых это не сторедж приложения, а во вторых если бы не отличался у вас бы все работало. Загуглите название устройства и моб браузера с которым у вас проблемы, может найдете что то

Comment: Ок, спасибо попробую.

Comment: Так у меня на всех мобильных устройствах так происходит.

Comment: покажите код, как записываете токен в сторедж/куки

Comment: await this.$axios.$get('user').then(response => {
      commit('user', response.success) 
    })

Comment: Отличный вопрос, без строчки кода. Начинается битва экстрасенсов

Comment: Может на телефоне просто включён "режим инкогнито"? С другого телефона пробовали входить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге смог решить вопрос. После долгих разбирательств выяснилось что модуль ставит cookie по умолчанию только на одну сессию. Надо было выставить `expires: число дней`, в `nuxt.config.js`. Это решило вопрос.

Comment: ну тут наши полномочия всё, молодцы что решили вопрос!

Answer (score 1):

Если соединение с сайтом происходит по протоколу http (не https), возможно, браузер на телефоне не сохраняет куки в целях безопасности. Переходите на https.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, может кому-то поможет, но не этот случай.